# Plotting simple graphs

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Hi everyone I encountered 2 cases where I derived two equivalent equations that give different graphs.

Case 1:

Using $T^2$ Vs $l$ in $T^2 = \displaystyle\frac{l}{4\pi^2g}$

Against $T$ Vs $\sqrt{l}$ in the same equation as $Y$ and $X$ variables respectively.

Case 2:

$\displaystyle\frac{L}{l-L}$ Vs $R$ in $\displaystyle\frac{L}{l-L}= \frac{R}{r}$

Against $1/L$ Vs $1/R$ in $\displaystyle\frac{1}{L} = \frac{1}{R}\cdot \frac{r}{l} + \frac{1}{l}$

Here $l$ and $r$ are constants

I'm confident the data is fine. I'm looking for clean linear graphs but I get curved graphs for the latter equation in each case even though I derived them from each other.
My question is why do I get different graphs?

Here is a google sheets link to the graphs I plotted:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lABgNxtJ_ZF7Rs9ytIhnANd-Fci5lA7otGIeUhgkAWU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't find a question in there sorry. Maybe take out a lot of un-necessary text and focus on your exact problem. Don't mention graphs if you are not going to show us a graph for example.

Comment: cleaned it up :)

Comment: $T$ vs $\sqrt{l}$ should give a straight line through the origin if the $T$ and $l$ data is ok. I cannot access your formulas in the spreadsheet to see if the problem is there. Graphs of $T^2$ vs $l$ and $ln(T)$ against $ln(l)$ should also give straight lines. Maybe check those too?

Comment: Yup I hadn't created a square root column, although the graph looks a little wobbly why is that? I've given editor access so you should be able to see the cell formulas now. And what about case 2?

Comment: Is the Column C, Row 7 value text rather than numerical? Seems to be throwing things off anyway. Case 2 looks straight and ok.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but nice catch! graph works perfectly now. :D